# How do i write a program that calculates the product of a number's digits that are different from another number i input?

Tags: c++, product, digits

I have to input 2 numbers, n and k, and find the product of n's digits which are different from k.
Example: n = 1234, k=2, and the product should be 1 * 3 * 4;

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, p=1, digit;
    cin >> n >> k;

    while(true){
            digit= n % 10;

        if(digit != k){
            p = p * digit;
        }
        n = n/10;
    }
    cout << "Product of digits different from K is: " << p;
    return 0;
}
```

When i run it, after i input n and k, the program doesnt do anything else and just keeps the console open without an output.

Comment: Ask yourself how that loop ever breaks.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, i actually forgot about breaking the loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `while(true)`. In this way the program stay in the loop for eternal.
A possible solution can be this:

```
int main()
{
    int n, k, p=1, digit;
    cin >> n >> k;

    while( n > 0 ){
            digit= n % 10;

        if(digit != k){
            p = p * digit;
        }
        n = n/10;
    }
    cout << "Product of digits different from K is: " << p;
    return 0;
}
```